# Find the current line number of a running python process

Tags: python, debugging

I have long-running python programs that do not have sufficient internal logging. I'd like to be able to attach to a running python program and find out it's current line number. Ideally, I'd like to do this without interrupting its execution, but I'm happy to have it pause, print the stack t race, and then keep going.

I could easily type control-C, but that would kill the program.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If you're fine with debugging kind of approach, try out pdb - 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: Thanks. `pdb` works great if you launch the program under pdb, but it doesn't look like it can attach to a running python program or perform introspection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like [py-spy](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy) is what you are looking for.

It can connect to running process without modifying and show what it currently does by using the command:

```
py-spy dump --pid 12345
```

Comment: py-spy it is! Thanks!

Comment: Note that it **does** 'modify' the running process in that it pauses it to read what it's doing in a consistent state. To avoid that, for example if your process seems to be hanging somewhere anyway (in my case it was hanging on a network read somewhere in a standard library, so the stack wasn't going to change), you can use `py-spy dump --nonblocking --pid 12345`